# Custom sort in PHP (by clothes sizes)

Tags: php

I'm currently using the following custom sort function, in order to sort by clothes sizes:

```
function sort_size($a, $b) {
    static $sizes = array('STANDART', 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', 'XXXXL', 'XXXXXL');

    $asize = 100;
    $apos = -1;
    $bsize = 100;
    $bpos = -1;

    foreach($sizes AS $val => $str) {
        if(($pos = strpos($a, $str)) !== FALSE && ($apos < 0 || $pos < $apos)) {
            $asize = $val;
            $apos = $pos;
        }

        if(($pos = strpos($b, $str)) !== FALSE && ($bpos < 0 || $pos < $bpos)) {
            $bsize = $val;
            $bpos = $pos;
        }
    }

    return($asize == $bsize ? 0 : ($asize > $bsize ? 1 : -1));
}

usort($color, 'sort_color');
```

But I get the following result:

```
S,M,L,XL,XXL,34,32,36,33,38,31,40
```

How can I modify it, in order to sort the `numbers` as well?

Comment: What do you want for a result?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sort_color($a, $b) {
    $sizes = [ .... ];
    $av = array_search($a, $sizes);
    $bv = array_search ($b, $sizes);
    if($av === FALSE or $bv === FALSE)
       throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unknown size $a or $b");
    return $av - $bv;
}
```

Comment: Well, it will be kind of ugly if my online store's customer see something like - Choose size: S, M, L, XL, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size, Unknown size. Don't you think?

Comment: Its up to you to ensure that $sizes contains all possible values. And your customer will not see Unknown size, he will see exception / error page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
function sortBySizes($sizeA, $sizeB)
{
    $sizes = [32, 'S', 34, 'M', 36, 'L', 38, 'XL'];

    $keyForSizeA = array_search($sizeA, $sizes);
    $keyForSizeB = array_search($sizeB, $sizes);

    if ($keyForSizeA === $keyForSizeB) return 0;

    return ($keyForSizeA > $keyForSizeB) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($clothes, "sortBySizes");
```

Simple function but you need to define all possible sizes in array `$sizes` for compare if you need to mix *S, M, L, XL* with *32, 34, 36, 38* values. Also if you do not want to define all *numbers values* (32, 34, ...) you can make associative array:

```
$array = [
    '32' => 'S',
    '34' => 'M',
    '36' => 'L',
];
```

Then `array_search()` return number size (of course you need to write condition if size is not *letter* value) and you can compare it with default *numeric* size.

Comment: The problem is, that it's not possible to know the possible sizes. If I knew them, I was just going to add them on my function.. :-))